# Set default date in DataBox

Tags: google-apps-script

In my project I have Task that i need to display calender,I'm using two dataBox that the user can use today and yesterday date , but i want to display default today and yesterday date in each DataBox
There is possibility to display default day with dataBox

```
var MyApp = UiApp.createApplication();
MyApp.add(MyApp.loadComponent("Create Reports"));
var Today_Date= MyApp.getElementById("TodayPanel")
var Yesterday_Date=MyApp.getElementById("YesterdayPanel");
var Today_dateBox = MyApp.createDateBox().setId("Today_DB");
var Yesterday_dateBox = MyApp.createDateBox().setId("Yesterdayday_DB");
Today_Date.add(Today_dateBox);
Yesterday_Date.add(Yesterday_dateBox);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(MyApp);
```

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateBox has a `setValue(Date)` function . Use that to set the date.

```
var ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 *1000;
var today = new Date(); 
var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - ONE_DAY);

Today_dateBox.setValue(today);
Yesterday_dateBox.setValue(yesterday);
```

Comment: Yes it works good thank you very much but i want an other thing please if yesterday will be Sunday he must display me last Sunday..how can i do this please.